# Is it possible to use @Grab inside a Gradle build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, groovy-grape

Is it possible to use @Grab inside a Gradle build.gradle file?

My understanding is that Gradle build scripts are written in Groovy and Grape/@Grab is built into Groovy.

But if i attempt to add a @Grab annotation into a build.gradle file it doesn't work.

e.g. adding:

```
@Grab(group='org.springframework', module='spring-orm', version='3.2.5.RELEASE')
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

it gives me the error

```
org.gradle.groovy.scripts.ScriptCompilationException: Could not compile build file.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/groovy-grab-syntax-equivalent-for-gradle/6598), the answer is no, we can't use `@Grab`.

However, there is an equivalent way to declare a dependency and add it to the classpath, as shown below (usage for the example: `gradle go`):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
}

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate

task go() {
    doLast {
        println 'TRACER : ' + JdbcTemplate.class.getSimpleName()
    }
}
```